# Updating table with another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I need to select entire columns from table compression_query_table into Tenth_mile but INSERT deletes columns already in that Table that aren't in Compression_query_Table and I cannot figure out how to use UPDATE on multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: You need to add more details about your problem for us to be able to help you.  What columns are in compression_query_table?  Columns in Tenth_mile?  What data is in those tables now (just give us a sample)?  What should that sample data look like after this query is run?

Comment: I am not even sure what you're asking right now based upon your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Three columns are session_name, state, and route_number. These columns both exist in both tables but are only populated in compression_query_table. I need to get the data from one table into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `session_name` is unique, you could probably write two separate statements: `INSERT` and `UPDATE` for this:

**Update Statement:**

```
UPDATE Tenth_mile
INNER JOIN compression_query_table cq on Tenth_mile.session_name = cq.session_name
SET Tenth_mile.State = cq.State,
    Tenth_mile.route_number = cq.route_number;
```

**Insert Statement:**

```
INSERT INTO Tenth_mile (session_name, state, route_number) 
SELECT session_name
    ,STATE
    ,route_number
FROM compression_query_table cq
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT tm.session_name
         FROM Tenth_Mile tm
      WHERE tm.session_name = cq.session_name
    );
```

> **Note:** I don't have MS-Access installed on my machine, so I don't have
>   a way to test this. Also, I would run the update before running the insert statement (aka `upsert`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That didn't work. The insert errors out and the update doesn't update.

Comment: @BenZeddicus Like I said, I don't have a way to test this. Can you please post what errors you are getting?

Comment: The insert is a syntax error and the update doesn't error but the tenth_mile table is just blank.

Comment: Yeah, that means there is nothing to update in that `tenth_mile` table. I just removed the unnecessary brackets in the `insert` statement, it should work for you now hopefully!

Comment: That is interesting. When I try this: 

INSERT INTO tenth_mile_copy
SELECT state FROM Compression_query_table;

It says that state isn't in the compression table, even though it definitely is.

Comment: I apologize, I think I figured it out, the error was due to keyword `VALUES` which is not needed when you are inserting data using a select statement.

Comment: That finally worked when I change the where not exists to where exists.

Comment: Great! But, wouldn't you want to only insert rows if it's not already in your `tenth_mile` table?

Comment: All the rows I want are already in the table, so I don't know why WHERE NOT EXISTS would work.

Another problem is that when I add date_of_data_Collection from compression table it only copies over some of the dates. Which is really weird.

Comment: Yeah, I am not really sure if I can help any further without looking at your data. Also, `Not Exists` ensures that you are not inserting rows into `tenth_mile` table if it already exists. Otherwise, you are just going to create duplicate rows if you don't have a constraint in `session_name` field.

Comment: But that is only a problem if the tenth mile table is already populated. It starts out as empty.

Comment: If that's the case then, I would just remove the `where exists` part.